# Hue not taking effect on scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am attempting to produce a scatter plot using 'hue' with the following dataframe:

```
count   xaxis           yaxis
355     -118.054250     34.134100
337     -118.244512     34.072581
284     -118.265586     34.043271
269     -118.360102     34.071338
241     -118.408160     33.943626
```

with the following code:

```
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
sns.relplot(x = 'xaxis', y = 'yaxis', data = countTest, hue = 'count')
```

[image: All data seems to be under the count of 60, which is incorrect]

As you can see, all the data points seem to indicate that the count is 60 or below, which is not the case.

Comment: Not reproducible in my environment, color coding works as expected with your sample data and code. "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Nope didn't work...should I do a clean install of seaborn? I am new to using Seaborn

Comment: Does the same behavior occur with just the five data points that you provided here? I reconstructed them with `countTest = pd.DataFrame({"count": [355, 337, 123, 269, 241],  "xaxis": [-118.054250, -118.244512, -118.265586, -118.360102, -118.408160], "yaxis": [34.134100, 34.072581, 34.043271, 34.071338, 33.943626]})`. Anything else we should know? Do you use an environment like Jupyter notebook or similar?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook, and it is working perfectly when I am using just the five data points. So I am assuming the issue is with the dataset size? I have 28,366 rows with 3 columns, memory usage of 665KB

Comment: Yup, probably something with your dataset. Have you checked for nan or inf values that may influence the seaborn behavior?

Comment: I did already remove those. Although I do get a slight change in results and colors when I am adding in `hue_norm=(0, 7)`. I will try and play around with the dataset. Thank you for your help